# Encrypt the web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I am trying to encrypt the ConnectioString of the web.config file.I ran the cmd as the administrator and gave the following commnad as

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef ProvantisDataConnection" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSOC"`

`Encrypting configuration section...`

`The configuration section 'ProvantisDataConnection' was not found.`

`Failed!`

I have the web.config file inside the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSOC` and th `<connectionStrings>` section in web.config as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ProvantisDataConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.00.00.0001)(PORT= 4321))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ABC))));User Id=ABCD ;Password=ABCDD;pooling=true;min pool size=5;Max Pool Size=60" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but it still throws as Failed.

Comment: Please post the ProvantisDataConnection node of your web.config (with connection string info removed)

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson I have edited my question with the ConnectionString section on it

Comment: I haven't used this feature in a while, but I'm 95% confident that you have to select a node by the name of the node, not an attribute value. Meaning that the correct node name to encrypt would be connectionStrings.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson I am not getting you, where will we be giving the node name and I am giving the name of the ConnectionString that needs to be encrypted

Comment: Change aspnet_regiis -pef ProvantisDataConnection to aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings

Comment: Awesome. It worked

Comment: Cool, I'll put it as an answer so it doesn't get buried for other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running aspnet_regiis, you need to indicate the name of the node you want to encrypt. You cannot select what you want to encrypt by an attribute value. Basically, change

```
aspnet_regiis -pef ProvantisDataConnection
```

to

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings
```